# Windows 10: Export and import system settings

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to export Windows 10 settings and re-import it after Windows has been reinstalled on the same device?

Comment: What settings do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods. For example, you could export the entire registry, and copy the entire profile folder. This will of course copy any clutter too.

A far easier way is to convert your local profile to an online profile and sync your profile with your Microsoft Account. It will store your settings in the profile.

So all you need to do is convert your local profile to a microsoft account reboot once.

Now, on the new machine, it is important that you first install all the software for which you may have settings, otherwise the installation may overwrite old settings. Also, keep a backup of your AppData in case the settings you wish to restore were not stored in the registry. They can be restored after the program is installed and after you logged into windows using your online account.

Once you migrated, you can convert your online account back into a local account.

If you like the idea of an online account, keep in mind that if you use that account to login on multiple devices, such as your main pc and your laptop, if you then change the background of your desktop, it will also be altered on the other device upon next reboot.